# Practice CSS and HTML without worrying about backend

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to practice CSS and HTML without worrying about whether the backend works or not, or whether or not I have to make the content. I've played around with javascript and node.js a bit, and although I feel like I have a (very) rudimentary understanding of it, I feel as if I should be learning HTML and CSS correctly before messing more with the backend.

Is there a good place to just write CSS and HTML? How did you learn them?

Is there a code editor I should be using (specifically for HTML layouts and CSS layouts) besides Sublime Text?

Comment: Give a try to [CODEACADEMY](http://www.codecademy.com/), [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) hope this two will be more positive comparing others. All the best. :)

Comment: You can use just Notepad or Notepad++, or any fancy free editor. You can open static HTML pages from disk without having to have a webserver.

Comment: If you have a static HTML file and Google Chrome, I'd recommend [Brackets](http://brackets.io) because it does live update as you type.

Comment: For code editor i will prefer [brackets](http://brackets.io/?lang=en) and [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: Thank you all, for your help. I gave brackets a shot, and I'm learning a lot by participating in Google code-in. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all, you do not worry about how backend works if what you want is to practice CSS and HTML.

---

**Easy steps to play around with HTML and CSS:**

1. create a new file, say `index.html`. Then, just `double click` on that file or `open with..` your favorite browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, Mozilla, or IE).
2. If you want CSS, you can attach it to the index.html by using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css">`.

**Note** : You would only need `Node.js` when you are dealing with `AJAX method` like using `XMLHttpRequest` or `$.ajax()` method due to `CORS (Cross Domain Policy`. Other than that, just play around with `HTML` and `CSS` with the browser.

---

**My Personal Journey to the Front End Web Development**

**About me**

I am currently working as a full time Front End Web Developer and I self-studied coding for 2 years now (I started this in June 2012) from almost zero knowledge about coding. When I started this, `HTML5` and `CSS3` were briefly introduced to the public so I learned `HTML4` beforehand.

`Web` is fairly a big topic if we talk about the full stack integration (from the browser to the server to the database). If you are into the front end (`HTML/CSS/Javascript`), start off with some online tutorials (link below), then try to create your own web product (it could be a website or a web app). Try to improve a bit by a bit, and if you ever get stuck, you can always google search your problem and try to find the solution online (usually `StackOverflow`).

**About Text Editor**

I think the best way to learn is to get your hands dirty with minimal code help as possible. This will force you to remember most of the syntax and in turn increase your productivity. I was using `Notepad++` but then switched to `Sublime Text` (Currently `Sublime Text 3`), and is my favorite text editor up until now. I know my co-worker is using `emacs` or `vim` that has a lot of keyboard shortcuts. Personally, `Sublime Text` is good enough to write `HTML` and `CSS`. Link: http://www.sublimetext.com/3

---

I started learning `HTML` and `CSS` from these links:

**Paid**

http://www.codeschool.com

**Free**

http://www.codeacademy.com

http://code.org

---

Hope it helps,

Yanuar Wibisono

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at w3schools [html](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) tutorials ?

They have a very handy "Try it yourself" button which allows you to try out your own code and see the results very quickly. The tutorials themselves are also well written with plenty of example code.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML and CSS, I would recommend the text editor Microsoft WebMatrix, which is a standard program for Windows. For learning HTML and CSS, check out http://codeacademy.com. It's one of the best places to learn HTML, CSS and a bunch of other coding languages.